# search for all string literals in an xcode project using the command line

Tags: xcode, bash, unix, grep

I know I can use `command + shift + f` to search an xcode project, and that I can choose to search using Regex in the "Search criterial Bar" as shown [here](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev35dbcdcf8) & find the string literals in the project using the regex `(\"[\w\s]+\")`. But, I'm trying to automate this process in a Bash scrip. So my question is, how can I performing a similar search using the command line that outputs a list of all the string literals in my project. I've been messing around with `grep` without much success.

Comment: Your question is unclear; what you are wanting to 'automate' or for that matter what are you wanting to do with the results. Maybe provide an example of what you are searching for also.

Comment: I'm trying to generate a list of all the string literals in the project. I'm just outputting them to a file, so I can generate a diff with all the new/changed string literals for QA purposes prior to each release.

Comment: So, did you solve it? Tried `grep -o '"[^"\]*\(\\.[^"\]*\)*"' file > outfile`? See [the online demo](https://ideone.com/EqMvJp)

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `grep` command like

```
grep -o '"[^"\]*\(\\.[^"\]*\)*"' file > outfile
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/RPWaPW):

```
s='"String1 \"here\""
"String2"'
grep -o '"[^"\]*\(\\.[^"\]*\)*"' <<< "$s";
```

The `"[^"\]*\(\\.[^"\]*\)*"` POSIX BRE pattern matches `"`, then any 0+ chars other than `\` and `"`, then any 0+ occurrences of `\` and then any char followed with any 0+ chars other than `\` and `"` and then a `"` char.

If you can use a PCRE enabled `grep`, you may use a safer expression that will only start matching at the first unescaped double quote:

```
grep -oP '(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\K"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"' file > outfile
```

Here, `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"` is the PCRE equivalent of the above POSIX BRE pattern and `(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\K` makes sure the first `"` is not escaped: `(?<!\\)` matches a location not preceded with `\`, then `(?:\\{2})*` matches 0 or more occurrences of double backslashes and then `\K` omits the text matched so far.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/e57NnT):

```
s='A culprit \" escaped quote and "String1 \"here\""
"String2"'
grep -oP '(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\K"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"' <<< "$s";
```

Both yield the following output:

```
"String1 \"here\""
"String2"
```